# Get value of dropdown menu from database

Tags: php, database

I have a drop-down menu and i want to select the value pf drop-down if the value is already saved in database for that option.

```
    <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category" required >
                <option value="">Select</option>
                <?
                $category= $rs2->fields['category'];                    
                ?>  
                <option value="1" <? if($category== $rs2->fields['category']) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>> PHP </option>
                <option value="2" <? if($category== $rs2->fields['category']) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>> JAVA </option>
                <option value="3" <? if($category== $rs2->fields['category']) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>> C++ </option>
                <option value="4" <? if($category== $rs2->fields['category']) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>> WordPress </option>
</select>
```

If category type is 3 in database then on page lode the selected value should be C++.

Comment: Why would you want to show a menu item when there is no corresponding database entry?

Comment: @Mawg I don't think that's what is being suggested. OP simply wants to set the _selected_ value based on the current value in the DB. Very standard stuff in a form

Comment: icic; sorry, I got confused

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to actually mention what's going wrong, but your code appears to be circular / tautologous.

You write

```
$category= $rs2->fields['category']
```

followed by

```
if($category== $rs2->fields['category'])
```

Of course the result of this `if` statement will always be true, because on the line right above you made the two variables have the same value by assigning the value of one to the other!

I thnk you need to write

```
if($rs2->fields['category'] == 1)
```

on the first line, and then replace 1 with 2 on the second line, etc? That way you test the DB field value against the option value.

Complete sample:

```
<select class="form-control" id="category" name="category" required >
  <option value="">Select</option>    
  <option value="1" <? if($rs2->fields['category'] == 1) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>> PHP </option>
  <option value="2" <? if($rs2->fields['category'] == 2) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>> JAVA </option>
  <option value="3" <? if($rs2->fields['category']  == 3) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>> C++ </option>
  <option value="4" <? if($rs2->fields['category'] == 4) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>> WordPress </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem. you need to check value of option with category.

```
<option value="1" <? if($category== 1) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>> PHP </option>
                    <option value="2" <? if($category== 2) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>> JAVA </option>
                    <option value="3" <? if($category== 3) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>> C++ </option>
                    <option value="4" <? if($category== 4) { echo 'selected="selected"'; } ?>> WordPress </option>
```